# How to use FaceRecognition in Java using Open CV

Tags: java, opencv

I am now currently developing face recognition system, my currently work is can detect face only but not recognizing it. I have some research like eigenface alogarithm but I dont know how to apply it on my codes. Can anyone here help me?

```
 if (webSource.grab()) {
                    try {
                        webSource.retrieve(frame);
                        Graphics g = jPanel1.getGraphics();
                        faceDetector.detectMultiScale(frame, faceDetections);
                        for (Rect rect : faceDetections.toArray()) {
                           // System.out.println("ttt");
                            Core.rectangle(frame, new Point(rect.x, rect.y), new Point(rect.x + rect.width, rect.y + rect.height),
                                    new Scalar(0, 255,0));
                        }
                        Highgui.imencode(".bmp", frame, mem);
                        Image im = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(mem.toArray()));
                        BufferedImage buff = (BufferedImage) im;
                        if (g.drawImage(buff, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight()-150 , 0, 0, buff.getWidth(), buff.getHeight(), null)) {
                            if (runnable == false) {
                                System.out.println("Paused ..... ");
                                this.wait();
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        System.out.println("Error!!");
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Can you show us what you tried already?

Comment: This is my currently work in faceDetection